# Estimating timeline or estimated timeline?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

What is the correct phrase to say in proper english:
Estimating timeline or estimated timeline?
Timeline is a noun so I conjecture that in front of it you should put an adjective. Thus my correct answer is Estimating Timeline. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Estimating** is a conjugated version of the verb **Estimate**

```
Bill was estimating the distance he'd need to throw the rock.
```

**Estimated** is also a past tense verb, but is used like an adjective to provide more information about the history of the **Timeline**

```
This is an estimated timeline
```

Therefore, the timeline is **estimated**

Edit: More information

Answer (score -1):

"Estimating (a/the) timeline" describes the process of guessing or roughly calculating the timeline.

"An/The estimated timeline" describes the result: not the process but the timeline itself.

The problem there seems to have been that "Estimating" is not adjective but a verb.